# summation of a series with Gamma function coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a closed form for F(x) given below:
 $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{\Gamma (a+n)x^n}{n!}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Hint: [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Many thanks achille hui.

Comment: Further hint: $F(x)=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{(1-x)^a}$ for any $|x|<1$. You can also use the integral representation $\Gamma(a+n)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}t^{a-1} t^n e^{-t}\,dt $ and switch $\sum$ and $\int$.